# Share actions between slices with Redux Toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

How can I share common actions in redux state slices?

Say I want to share `updateField` defined below in multiple slices other than `profile`. Should I import it from external file?

I could use `extraReducers` from `@redux/toolkit` but then I should create a new slice containing my `updateField` action and that action don't have state of its own. It just use the state of the slice it's imported in.

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const INITIAL_STATE = { title: { value: '' } }

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'profile',
  initialState: INITIAL_STATE,
  reducers: {

    updateField: (state, { payload: { name, value } }) => ({
      ...state,
      [name]: {
        ...state.data[name],
        value,
      },
    }),

  },
})

export const {
  updateField,
} = slice.actions
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what the commonality is? Is it the reducer function implementation that is common and you just want to make your code more **DRY**? Is it that you want other reducers to also handle the `profile/updateField` action type?

Comment: @DrewReese The first case: I want to share the function implementation so I can call `profile/updateField`, `user/updateField`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to implement a single reducer function you can certainly define it once and export/import into the slices that need it.

Example:

```
export const updateField = (state, { payload: { name, value } }) => ({
  ...state,
  [name]: {
    ...state.data[name],
    value,
  },
})
```

Profile slice

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { updateField } from '../path/to/updateField'; // <-- import

export const INITIAL_STATE = { title: { value: '' } }

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'profile',
  initialState: INITIAL_STATE,
  reducers: {
    updateField, // <-- pass to reducers object
  },
});
```

User slice

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { updateField } from '../path/to/updateField'; // <-- import

export const INITIAL_STATE = { title: { value: '' } }

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState: INITIAL_STATE,
  reducers: {
    updateField, // <-- pass to reducers object
  },
});
```

Comment: Yes, but when I `export const { updateField } = slice.actions`, I got a `'updateField' has already declared` error

Comment: @Tom So either use a different name when importing, or a different name when exporting. A different name when importing is easier, `import { updateField as updateFieldReducer } from '../path/to/updateField';` and then pass into the slice as `updateField: updateFieldReducer`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `extraReducers` property on `createSlice` to listen to custom actions.

```
// actions
export const incrementBy = createAction<number>('incrementBy')

// reducers

const counter1 = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: 0,
  reducers: {
    decrement: (state) => state - 1,
  },
  // "builder callback API"
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(incrementBy, (state, action) => {
      return state + action.payload
    })
  },
})

const counter2 = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: 0,
  reducers: {
    decrementByTwo: (state) => state - 2,
  },
  // "builder callback API"
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(incrementBy, (state, action) => {
      return state + action.payload
    })
  },
})
```

Comment: Quoted from the official docs, “In this case, you might define some common action types in a separate file using `createAction`, import those action creators into each slice file, and handle them using the `extraReducers` argument."
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#exporting-and-using-slices

Comment: @hychou agreed, skipped here for brevity